# Multi table joins - can I add an outer join to this?

Tags: sql, outer-join

I'm having a problem moving from a situation where an Outer Join works, to where it fails.

Working (pseudo code example)

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref
FROM jobs a, teams b LEFT OUTER JOIN teamfirms c ON b.ref = c.team
WHERE a.ref = b.job
```

There is a many to one relationship between jobs and teams (many teams per job) that is *always* populated

There may or may not be firms in table c, but the query above gives me the result I would expect (approx 5000 records)

The problem comes when I want to bring in the details about the teams from a fourth table

The code I am trying is below

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref, d.name
FROM jobs a, teams b LEFT OUTER JOIN teamfirms c ON b.ref = c.team, firms d
WHERE a.ref = b.job
AND d.ref = c.firmref
```

At this point the NULLS that I am trying to capture disappear and I drop approx 500 records

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should never use implicit joins. This is a poor practice and results in problems with unintended cross joins and issues in maintenance when you need to add left joins. And mixing implict and explicit joins is a prescription for incorrect results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a whack at this.

```
select a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref, d.name
from jobs a left outer join teams b on b.job = a.ref
left outer join teamfirms c on b.ref = c.team
left outer join firms d on c.firmref = d.ref
left outer join table e on a.column = e.column
```

or you could do

```
select a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref, d.name
from
jobs a, teams b, teamfirms c, firms d
where
a.ref = b.job
and b.ref = c.team
and c.firmref = d.ref
```

one or the other... not both.

Just to throw this in for good measure...

> You use INNER JOIN to return all rows
>   from both tables where there is a
>   match. ie. in the resulting table all
>   the rows and colums will have values.
>
> LEFT OUTER JOIN returns all the rows
>   from the first table, even if there
>   are no matches in the second table.
>
> RIGHT OUTER JOIN returns all the rows
>   from the second table, even if there
>   are no matches in the first table.

Comment: This is a much clearer way of writing it - though from the question it looks like the first join should be an inner one... not sure if that is how it is intended though.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've never been able to get my head around explicit Joins using more that a pair of tables and I think that this sorts it!

Comment: I think an Inner will suffice for the first join as there should never be any gaps between the two tables.

Comment: Assuming that the above is correct, How would I expand this to get further information from another table (e) that links from table a or b?

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing ANSI 89 and 92 JOIN syntax (implicit and explicit JOINs).  Try converting the entire query to explicit JOINs.  The problem is likely that the new JOIN you're adding (implicit syntax) is INNER and wants to be OUTER, or that you want to resolve the JOINs in a different order (which you can do with parens once you write them all as OUTER JOINs)

Answer (score 0):

Try, the following:

```
SELECT 
  a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref, d.name 
FROM 
 jobs a, teams b 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN teamfirms c ON b.ref = c.team
        LEFT OUTER JOIN firms d on c.firmref = d.ref
WHERE a.ref = b.job
```

If it works, you could then try to turn the 2nd LEFT OUTER into an INNER.  Possibly incorrectly I've generally left it as an outer when I've needed this sort of thing.

Comment: I see a drive by -1 with no comment going on.  Please enlighten us to why otherwise we can't improve our answers

Comment: Yes, sorry that was me, @Larry explains it well.

Comment: @Mr Shoubs:  Thanks - I did see @Larry's answer and it gives very good answer providing the theory as to why too.  It was possibly just missing the example as to what his request actually meant.  Several other people gave the same example pretty much at the same time as me too by the looks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref, d.name 
FROM jobs a
 join teams b on (b.job = a.ref)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN teamfirms c ON (b.ref = c.team)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN firms d on (d.ref = c.firmref)
```

This will join all jobs to team and if a teamfirm exist then also bring firm details.  if no team firm relationship you still get your nulls.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.ref, c.ref, c.firmref, d.name
FROM jobs a, teams b LEFT OUTER JOIN teamfirms c ON b.ref = c.team
LEFT OUTER JOIN firms d ON c.firmref = d.ref
WHERE a.ref = b.job
```