# Joining One table to many using Joins

Tags: sql, join

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156341/multi-table-joins-can-i-add-an-outer-join-to-this) it's finally clicked how to write joins between multiple tables, where they link in a line e.g.

```
Table A - Table B - Table C
```

Where Table A references Table B, and Table B references Table C and so on.

What I still don't understand is how to reference the situation where Table A references Table B as above and *also* reference Table D.

In implicit Joins I can get the following to work, but want to move it to explicits...

```
SELECT a.name, b.office, c.firm, d.status
FROM job a, depts b, firms c, statuses d
WHERE a.office = b.ref
AND b.firm  = c.ref
AND a.status = d.ref
```

Any tips?

Comment: Good for you on moving away from implicit joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    b.office, 
    c.firm, 
    d.status
FROM 
    job a
JOIN depts b ON a.office = b.ref
JOIN firms c ON b.firm  = c.ref
JOIN statuses d ON a.status = d.ref
```

That's as detailed as I could get on such an obscure question. You didn't describe what exactly does "link" mean in your case. So I don't know, maybe you need left join.

Comment: That's it!  I'd tried to be as generic as possible, in some cases the joins will be inner, in other cases outer.  That's for me to sort out :)